# is there a compiler flag for opening/closing flush-to-zero mode in c++ armv8?

Tags: c++, arm, clang, armv8

my compiler is clang, I don't know how to open flush-to-zero mode in armv8, could anyone tell me?
I find some flag like this`-fdenormal-fp-math=[values]`,but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the clang version, for example, I had clang 3.8 and got the following error `clang: error: unknown argument: '-fdenormal-fp-math=preserve-sign'`, but then installed clang 5.0 and it works just fine.

`clang++-5.0 hello.cpp -fdenormal-fp-math=preserve-sign`

Values are:

- ieee
- preserve-sign
- and positive-zero

Hope it helps.